# Pessimistic locking is not working with Query API

Tags: hibernate, pessimistic-locking

```
List esns=session.createQuery("from Pool e where e.status=:status "+
                        "order by uuid asc")
                        .setString("status", "AVAILABLE")
                        .setMaxResults(n)
                        .setLockMode("e", LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
                        .list();
```

I have the above query written, however it is not generating `for update` query and simultaneous updates are happening.

I am using 3.5.2 version and it has a [bug in Criteria API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028478/how-to-specify-pessimistic-lock-with-criteria-api), is the same bug present in query API as well or I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

setLockOptions is working fine. It is the [same bug as this one](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-5275).

Answer (score 1):

Try to use LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT, take a look at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29963687/why-my-pessimistic-locking-in-jpa-with-oracle-is-not-working).