# Should we use LockOptions instead of LockMode in hibernate query?

Tags: hibernate, locking

I see two classes for locking in hibernate -

1. `LockOptions`
2. `LockMode`

What is the difference between the two? When to use each?

Answer (score 1):

Referring to the Session javadoc http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/javadocs/, LockMode parameter should be replaced with LockOptions.

Here is the excerpt from the javadoc.

@Deprecated
Object load(String entityName,
                     Serializable id,
                     LockMode lockMode)
**Deprecated. LockMode parameter should be replaced with LockOptions**
Return the persistent instance of the given entity class with the given identifier, obtaining the specified lock mode, assuming the instance exists.

Parameters:

entityName - a persistent class

id - a valid identifier of an existing persistent instance of the class

lockMode - the lock level

Returns:

the persistent instance or proxy

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a definite answer but for MySQL the only way to generate a `for update` sql statement was:

```
query.setLockOptions(LockOptions.UPGRADE);
```

Comment: Are you sure? Or are you talking about this bug? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028478/how-to-specify-pessimistic-lock-with-criteria-api

Comment: Yes, most probably it's the bug you mention. Thanks.